# TypeORM migrations don't run automatically on server start

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, nest

Stack: nx, NestJS, TypeORM 3.x, Postgres

I finished configuring the TypeORM migrations mechanism with some inspiration from multiple solutions and the result is that I am currently able to run them using the CLI command:

```
env-cmd -f apps/api/.env.local -- typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run -d apps/api/src/app/configuration/typeorm/migrations.configuration.ts
```

The problem is that I want to run the new migrations automatically when the server (re)starts, and the `migrationsRun: true` flag which is supposed to do this is not working properly.

- Migrations configuration (data source):

  ```
  export default NestFactory.create(ConfigModule.forRoot()).then(async () => {
    const dataSourceOptions =
      (await new TypeOrmConfigService().createTypeOrmOptions()) as DataSourceOptions;
    return new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);
  });
  ```
- TypeORM config service (options factory):

  ```
  export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
    public async createTypeOrmOptions(): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> {
      const config = generateEnvironmentConfig();

      if (!config) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(
          'Type ORM instantiation error. The environment configuration is corrupted.'
        );
      }

      const databaseConfig = (config as IEnvironment)
        .database as IDatabaseEnvironment;
      const productionMode = (config as IEnvironment).production as boolean;

      return {
        type: 'postgres',
        host: databaseConfig.host,
        port: databaseConfig.port,
        database: databaseConfig.database,
        username: databaseConfig.credentials.adminUser,
        password: databaseConfig.credentials.adminPass,
        logger: productionMode ? 'file' : 'advanced-console',
        logging: ['error'],
        synchronize: !productionMode, //never use TRUE in production (also, optional locally when we use migrations)
        ssl: databaseConfig.useSSL && {
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
        },
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        migrations: [
          join(__dirname, '../../database/postgres/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'),
        ],
        migrationsRun: true,
      };
    }
  }
  ```
- POC migration:

  ```
  export class AddDefaultRoles1696090662112 implements MigrationInterface {
    rolesToAdd: string[] = [
      'Compliance Officer',
      'Auditor',
      'Reviewer',
      'Administrator',
    ];

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
      await Promise.all(
        this.rolesToAdd.map(async (role: string) => {
          const persistedGivenRole = await queryRunner.query(
            `SELECT id, type
              FROM user_data.role WHERE type='${role}';`
          );

          if (!persistedGivenRole || !persistedGivenRole.length) {
            await queryRunner.query(
              `INSERT INTO user_data.role(
                id, type)
                VALUES ('${uuidv4()}', '${role}');`
            );
          }
        })
      );
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    public async down(_queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
      // no reverting logic required
    }
  }
  ```
- App module:

  ```
  @Module({
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({
        isGlobal: true,
        load: [generateEnvironmentConfig],
      }),
      TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({ useClass: TypeOrmConfigService }),
      ...
  ```